# Javamail appendMessages throws IOException No Content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to copy messages from one IMAP store to another.

The line of code that does the actual copying is:

```
folder.appendMessages(new Message[] { m });
```

Most messages are copied with no problem, but some fail with:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while appending messages;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: No content
```

The stacktrace points to [IMAPFolder.java:1767](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.5.2/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.java#1767)

Some of the messages that were copied successfully were as large as 6MB, while some of the ones that failed were as small as 16KB in my test case, so it is not a size issue.

I'm not certain, but it's possible that the messages that fail has an attachment.  The content type `multipart/ALTERNATIVE` was found in both in the group of messages that failed and the group that succeeded.

Opening the failed messages in a mail client like Thunderbird works properly, so the messages are not corrupted.

### UPDATE:

`mail.imap.fetchsize` plays a role with this problem.  When it is the default of 16,384b, running over a sample of 1000 messages the smallest failed message is 16,432b -- slightly over the fetchsize.

When I increased it to 65,536b -- the smallest failed message of that same sample is 65,787b -- slightly over the fetchsize again.

The message with size 16,432b that consistently failed with the default fetchsize, copied successfully with the higher fetchsize, so this is definitely an issue here.

---

Any idea what causes this problem?

How can I copy the messages with having this issue?

TIA!

p.s. I'm using Java 1.7u71 and Javamail 1.5.2

Comment: It would help to have the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  It may be a bug in one of the mail servers.  What mail servers are you using?  Are you doing anything with the messages before appending them to the other store/folder?

Comment: @BillShannon - Thank you for your prompt attention to this.  I've pasted the debug output of a failed message at http://pastebin.com/LGUaVKfW -- This message fails consistently while it opens up properly in Thunderbird.

Comment: To answer your other questions, the server is modusMail IMAP4S 4.5.654.0 (as per the debug output), and I am not doing anything with the messages.  I simply iterate over the message at the `source-server`, and for each message I ensure that it does not exist on the `target-server` a-la `getMessageId()`, and if it does not exist I call `appendMessages()` as stated in the question above.

Comment: @BillShannon - `mail.imap.fetchsize` plays a role here.  Please see update in the question above.

Comment: We probably need to take this debugging offline.  Please contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.  I don't see anything obviously wrong in the debug output.  Before appending the message, can you add m.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")); and see if that produces the "No content" exception as well?

Comment: `m.writeTo()` produces the same error, at `at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.fill(IMAPInputStream.java:167)
`.  I emailed you more details.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on our offline discussion, setting the `mail.imap.partialfetch` property to `false` causes it to work.  When that happens, it's almost always because the server is broken in some way.

See also:

[Javamail Notes](https://javamail.java.net/docs/NOTES.txt) under "A list of the known limitations, bugs, issues" sections 4 and 5.

[Javamail FAQ, Fetch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#fetch)

Comment: Thank you Bill for your great help!  I edited your answer to include reference links.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was fixed in **Java Mail 1.6**

> https://javaee.github.io/javamail/